# Find the angles in degrees

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In quadrilateral ${ABCD}$, we know $AB=BC=CD$. If $\widehat {ABC}=150$ and $\widehat {BCD}=90$, then find angles $\widehat {CDB}$ and $\widehat {CDA}$ in degrees.

Comment: What have you tried?  You can let the equal sides be $1$ because the angles are the same in similar figures.  Now draw AD and use the law of cosines to get its length.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint: Draw the figure for some arbitrary length of $AB$.

Afterwards investigate the triangle $BCD$ and calculate all its remaining sides and angles.

Finally to conclude, take a look at the triangle $ABD$, for which you now should know two side lengths and the inclosing angle. Therefore use the [**law of cosines**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Answer (score 0):

The angle $ \widehat {BDC} =45$ degrees.

Use Law of cosines to the triangle BCD and find the length of BD in terms of the length of BC.

Then use Law of sines to triangle ABD to get the angle $\widehat { BDA}=30 $degrees.

Thus the angle $ \widehat {CDA} =75$ degrees.

Comment: $\widehat {BCD}=90$

Comment: I meant $\widehat {BDC}=45. Thanks for attention. Just edited my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AC\cap BD=\{K\}$ and $AB\cap CD=\{L\}$.

Thus, since $\measuredangle BCD=15^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle DBC=45^{\circ},$ we obtain $\measuredangle CKD=15^{\circ}+45^{\circ}=60^{\circ}.$

Thus, since $\measuredangle ALD=60^{\circ},$ we see that $BLCK$ is cyclic.

Hence, $$\measuredangle BLK=\measuredangle BCK=\measuredangle BAC,$$ which gives $$AK=KL.$$
Also, $$\measuredangle CLK=\measuredangle CBK=\measuredangle BDC,$$
which says $$DK=KL.$$
Id est, $$AK=KD,$$
$$\measuredangle KDA=30^{\circ}$$ and
$$\measuredangle CDA=30^{\circ}+45^{\circ}=75^{\circ}.$$